# Binding readonly value in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, data-binding

I need to bind a text area's readonly property to a property in my EmberJS component, but the readonly property (as well as the disabled property), don't take values; their presence alone gives their behavior. From this discussion:
[GitHub discussion](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11828)

This appears to be a regression, as per the discussion, before 1.13.3, the readonly property was bindable. Now, the presence of the attribute in an EmberJS, {{textarea readonly=false}}, with or without a value yields a read-only text area. Has anyone else run into this? Any work arounds?

Comment: Or you can extend textarea and use a custom attribute which will be observed and readonly can be applied through jquery based on the custom attribute.

Comment: `disabled` should work fine for you. Only `readonly` causes readonly just by presence.

Comment: Can you provide the jQuery syntax for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't run into this issue with ember 1.13.9. Maybe because I don't use textare or maybe because I use ember-cli-materialize for UI. I see a workaround in creating own component, that will wrap textarea in if block. Something like

```
//app/templates/components/my-textarea.hbs
{{#if readonly}}
  {{textarea readonly="readonly" value=value}}
{{else}}
  {{textarea value=value}}
{{/if}}
```

Not ideal solution, but should work

Comment: `{{textarea disabled=disabled value=value}}` doesn't work??

Comment: @AcidBurn personally, I didn't have any problems with disabled. I just posted an example how such problem can be solved. I think I should edit my answer and change disabled to readonly to prevent confusion.

Comment: The disabled attribute, like the readonly attribute does not require a value to work. Its presence alone is enough to disable the element. When used in an Ember input helper, a value has to be supplied, otherwise you'll get a build error, but the value itself is superfluous.

Comment: Ah ok. The docs also say so. But there seems to some confusion about this. For me `disabled=disabled` works fine. Ty for the info.

Comment: Ah yes, disabled=disabled does toggle the disabled attribute. I stand corrected.